# How do I add an .obj file from a relative file location?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, import, development

I need help adding an .obj file via scripting. I've tried using this line of code, but I'm having issues importing the obj file:

```py
bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath="./example.obj")
```

*I think the problem is how I define the file path, but I don't know how to fix it.*

Comment: To make the path relative to the blender file use `path = "//fileinsamefolderasblend.obj"`

Comment: @batFINGER Can I specify a path relative to the script (not the blend file)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+path+relative+to++script+

Comment: @batFINGER
`dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)  (newline)  file = os.path.join(dir, 'example.obj')  (newline)  bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=file)`
I tried this (from the search) and it also doesn't work. I have `os` imported.

Comment: Where, what is the script, how are you running it?  If blend file  is saved use as commented above to get path relative to blend file.  . If not saved then reverts to "." which is the folder from where blender is run.  eg if start blender from console from desktop folder this is where. If you are running from program  icon, possibly your install folder.  Recommend using `pathlib`    `import pathlib; print(pathlib.Path.cwd())`.   If the script is imported as an addon then `__dir__` above will work as expected.  If you are running script from main thread via text editor ...?

Comment: Agree with batFINGER Add how you are running the script.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to combine your relative path with the current directory, which you can get using the **os library**:

```
import os
bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=os.getcwd()+"/example.obj")
```

Comment: I recommend using [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to be on the safe side...

Answer (score 0):

```
import bpy
file_loc = 'C:\Models\Model.obj'
imported_object = bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=file_loc)
obj_object = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
print('Imported name: ', obj_object.name)
```

[Result](https://gyazo.com/8909f523913b56989294a480e111a0cf)

Comment: How would I grab a .obj in the same folder as the script? (aka a relative path)

Comment: If you run it inside blender, I think it uses blender’s location, and you have to put a path in here, but I am not sure